# How to name a worksheet depending on the text in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to name a worksheet depending on the entered text of a cell with:

```
Sheet2.Name = Range("C2")
```

This is working in another macro:

```
Sub Sheetname()
Sheet3.Unprotect
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect
Sheet3.Name = Range("C2")
Sheet3.Protect ""
ThisWorkbook.Protect
End Sub
```

On my main macro it gives me

> Run-Time error '1004'
>   Method 'Name' of object'_Worksheet' failed

```
Sub write_date_plant1()
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect
Sheets("Total").Unprotect
Sheets("MPT").Unprotect
Dim score As Integer
score = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now())
'score = Range("B1").Value
If score = Worksheets("MPT").Range("B3") Then
    Sheets("MPT").Range("B4").Value = Sheet2.Range("ok_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("B5").Value = Sheet2.Range("minor_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("B6").Value = Sheet2.Range("pdca_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("B7").Value = Sheet2.Range("major_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("B8").Value = Sheet2.Range("nope_plant1").Value
End If
...

If score = Worksheets("MPT").Range("Q3") Then
    Sheets("MPT").Range("Q4").Value = Sheet2.Range("ok_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("Q5").Value = Sheet2.Range("minor_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("Q6").Value = Sheet2.Range("pdca_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("Q7").Value = Sheet2.Range("major_plant1").Value
    Sheets("MPT").Range("Q8").Value = Sheet2.Range("nope_plant1").Value
End If       
Sheets("Total").Range("C4") = Date
Sheet2.Name = Range("C2")
Sheets("Total").Protect
Sheets("MPT").Protect
ThisWorkbook.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't specified a sheet for C2 so perhaps the contents of C2 on the active sheet are not a valid name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most common cause of a run-time Error 1004 is when VBA code refers to a named range that doesn’t exist. Perhaps the name is spelled wrong in the code. Or maybe an invalid name is used.

Check if all your ranges exist:

```
Sheets("Total")
Sheets("MPT")

Sheet2.Name = Range("C2")
Sheet2.Range("ok_plant1")
Sheet2.Range("minor_plant1")
Sheet2.Range("pdca_plant1")
Sheet2.Range("pdca_plant1")
Sheet2.Range("nope_plant1")
```

Check all the above ranges if they exist.

Comment: "Method 'Name' of object'_Worksheet'" is `Sheet2.Name`.

Comment: I named the cell but forgot to change it in the macro, many thanks.